# I Need to redirect WordPress pages to https but not the posts

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I need to keep https on for all posts on my wordpress website but need the pages to be redirected to http.

At the moment I am using the following to turn off all https:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How can I change this so that https is turned off for pages only and the ssl is still active on all posts.

Thank you.

Comment: Have no idea why you would do so, but i guess you can redirect from your page template file? or create a function that check if it is a page or post, and redirects it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

something like, not sure if it would work though.

This should check if you are using ssl/https, and if you are on a page, if so redirect you to the same one without the s.

The 301 redirect is implemented, so you don't have to worry about that.

```
    function unique_ssl_template_redirect() {

    if ( is_ssl() && is_page() ) {

        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {

            wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
            exit();

        } else {

            wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit();

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'unique_ssl_template_redirect', 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you Stender. You are a STAR! That worked great. Added to functions.php and did the job beautifully!

Comment: @MichaelMcGrath No worries m8 - no thanks neccesary, but i do appreciate an accept on my answer ;)